# Touch not detecting?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitouch

I am facing a problem related `UITouch`. I don't the reason why It's not going with the if case.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches  anyObject];
    if([touch view] == self.transView)
    {
        NSLog(@"Began");
        CGPoint startLocation    = [touch locationInView:transView];
        startX = startLocation.x;
        startY = startLocation.y;
    }
}
```

I am detecting touch on SubView. I added another class's `View` as subview and this class contains `UIImageView` on background . For e.g.

```
UIImageView *BGImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"graphBG.png"]];
[BGImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[BGImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(25, 365, 723, 390)];
[BGImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:BGImageView];
[self.view addSubview:BGImageView];
//[BGImageView release];
myGraph=[[MyGraphControllerView alloc]init];
myGraph.dataForPlot= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<[hoursArry count]; i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dataDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dataDict setObject:[dayArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"x"];
    [dataDict setObject:[HoursArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"y"];
    [myGraph.dataForPlot addObject:dataDict];
    [dataDict release];
}
[myGraph.view setFrame:CGRectMake(25, 380, 723, 390)];
//[myGraph.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:myGraph.view];
}
```

I have already added a subview on `GraphView` but it did not work.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to confirm: Why are you enabling the user interaction on UIImageView??
Set it's intraction disable so that view below it will now be the responder for touches. Kindly update if it doesn't work as i just read your 3 lines of code & you might have some other problem which might be not clear from here.

Answer (score 0):

```
//add gesture to mapview-for single touch
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SLideTheView:)];
[touchableView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
```

I would suggest to go with gesture for the view that needs touch to be detected.

Answer (score 0):

you are checking whether it is touching some view named self.transView